# How to add a table indicator in SELECT UNION Statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with the same columns

A

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
00    AA    1
00    AB    2
01    AC    1
```

B

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
00    AA    1
00    AB    2
00    AC    2
```

I want to join these tables with a union so that there is only one instance of every row.

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION
SELECT * FROM B
```

This gives me :

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
00    AA    1
00    AB    2
01    AC    1
00    AC    2
```

This is exactly what I want.  However; I would like to know from which table each row is from.  I tried adding a 4th column to work as a table indicator but of course when I use UNION every row from each table is technically unique.  Is there some way of getting this result?

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
00    AA    1     AB
00    AB    2     AB
01    AC    1     A
00    AC    2     B
```

Comment: Seems lilke what you want isn't a `UNION`  but a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Larnu Can you expound a little bit? I still don't see how the ```SQL FULL OUTER JOIN``` adds that table indicator

Comment: You can then use a `CASE` expression to check if the relevant table's column is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, seems like what you actually want is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(A.Col1,B.Col1) AS Col1,
       COALESCE(A.Col2,B.Col2) AS Col2,
       COALESCE(A.Col3,B.Col3) AS Col3,
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN A.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A' END,
              CASE WHEN B.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'B' END) AS Col4
FROM dbo.A
     FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
                          AND A.Col2 = B.Col2
                          AND A.Col3 = B.Col3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will struggle because you use UNION which removes duplicates - both within a single table and between tables. So rather than rely on UNION for that, use aggregation instead.

```
with cte as (
    select *, 't1' as tbl from @t1
    union all
    select *, 't2' as tbl from @t2
)
select Col1, Col2, Col3, min(tbl) as tbl
from cte
group by Col1, Col2, Col3
order by Col1, Col2, Col3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=986d2f38e83311d08524aebe1beb7d2c). Note that I ignore the possibility of NULL values in your table. I'll leave that to you to address if needed. Perhaps reconsider the decisions that led you to use 2 identical tables?

Comment: I don't see why there is any difference if there are nulls, it's perfectly valid to have a `null` group